# REPEAT onload animation onclick - Raphael Javascript SVG animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, raphael, repeat

I've been trying to make a raphael animation, it's working fine and animating on load as it should but..
I want it to animate AGAIN when clicking a text or button (a div outsite raphael paper).

Raphael Code is here:

window.onload = function () {
var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('frivardihouse'), 250, 250);

```
function round(value, precision) {
    var multiplier = Math.pow(10, precision || 0);
    return Math.round(value * multiplier) / multiplier;
}

let ltv = 0.6;
let h = 144*ltv;
let y = 86+((1-ltv)*144);
let ltvtxt = round(ltv * 100);


var fillhouse = paper.rect(40.5,230,172.3,0).attr({fill: "#ff6600", stroke: "none"});

var sAnimation = Raphael.animation({ 'width': 172.3, 'height': h, 'x': 40.5, 'y': y, fill: "#ff0066"}, 2000, "backOut")
fillhouse.animate(sAnimation);


var thehouse = paper.path("M236.5,80.4L128.9,2.1c-1.6-1.1-3.7-1.1-5.3,0L16.1,80.4c-3.5,2.6-1.7,8.1,2.6,8.1l13,0c-1,2.5-1.5,5.3-1.5,8.2l0,122.7c0,12,9.2,21.7,20.6,21.7l150.9,0c11.4,0,20.6-9.7,20.6-21.7l0-122.7c0-2.9-0.5-5.7-1.5-8.2h13C238.2,88.6,240,83,236.5,80.4z M206.7,104.9l0,106.5c0,9-6.9,16.3-15.5,16.3l-129.9,0c-8.5,0-15.5-7.3-15.5-16.3l0-106.5c0-9,6.9-16.3,15.5-16.3l129.9,0C199.8,88.6,206.7,95.9,206.7,104.9z").attr({fill: "#ccc", stroke: "none"});
};
```

I made a fiddle.

I tried normal click functions, but just can't seem to get it to work :( Nothing is happening. Really frustrating!

[See fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/mafLsbxh/2/)

Comment: are you still looking for answers for your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add the click event to `.clickme` class with jquery.

```
$('.clickme').click(function(){
    document.getElementById('frivardihouse').innerHTML = '';
    onload();
});
```

Below is the full code

```js
     onload = function () {
        var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('frivardihouse'), 250, 250);
        
    function round(value, precision) {
        var multiplier = Math.pow(10, precision || 0);
        return Math.round(value * multiplier) / multiplier;
    }

    let ltv = 0.6;
    let h = 144*ltv;
    let y = 86+((1-ltv)*144);
    let ltvtxt = round(ltv * 100);


    var fillhouse = paper.rect(40.5,230,172.3,0).attr({fill: "#ff6600", stroke: "none"});

    var sAnimation = Raphael.animation({ 'width': 172.3, 'height': h, 'x': 40.5, 'y': y, fill: "#ff0066"}, 2000, "backOut")
    fillhouse.animate(sAnimation);


    var thehouse = paper.path("M236.5,80.4L128.9,2.1c-1.6-1.1-3.7-1.1-5.3,0L16.1,80.4c-3.5,2.6-1.7,8.1,2.6,8.1l13,0c-1,2.5-1.5,5.3-1.5,8.2l0,122.7c0,12,9.2,21.7,20.6,21.7l150.9,0c11.4,0,20.6-9.7,20.6-21.7l0-122.7c0-2.9-0.5-5.7-1.5-8.2h13C238.2,88.6,240,83,236.5,80.4z M206.7,104.9l0,106.5c0,9-6.9,16.3-15.5,16.3l-129.9,0c-8.5,0-15.5-7.3-15.5-16.3l0-106.5c0-9,6.9-16.3,15.5-16.3l129.9,0C199.8,88.6,206.7,95.9,206.7,104.9z").attr({fill: "#ccc", stroke: "none"});


    };
    $('.clickme').click(function(){
    document.getElementById('frivardihouse').innerHTML = '';
     onload();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="frivardihouse"></div>

    <div class="clickme">
    CLICK ME AND REPEAT ANIMATION
    </div>
```

Comment: That's so weird, I already tried that but it didn't work. I'll try and implement it in my original files :-) Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any idea why I get this error when hiding and showing the house?
Error: <tspan> attribute dy: Expected length, "NaN".

See fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/5mv0enuz/2/

(i know the gauge is showing twice)

Comment: tspan errors only happen when the animation is still going With the above modification, it only happens when the gauge is still animating and you change it to the house. The gauge animation is still running and you change it to the house and gauge animation is stopped at that point and house animation is running.

Answer (score 0):

Without JQuery yes its possible!

Use `dispatchEvent(new Event('load'));` to trigger onload event from JS..

```
var clickEle = document.getElementsByClassName("clickme")[0];
clickEle.addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("frivardihouse").innerHTML = "";
  dispatchEvent(new Event('load'));
});
```

```js
onload = function() {
  var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('frivardihouse'), 250, 250);

  function round(value, precision) {
    var multiplier = Math.pow(10, precision || 0);
    return Math.round(value * multiplier) / multiplier;
  }

  let ltv = 0.6;
  let h = 144 * ltv;
  let y = 86 + ((1 - ltv) * 144);
  let ltvtxt = round(ltv * 100);


  var fillhouse = paper.rect(40.5, 230, 172.3, 0).attr({
    fill: "#ff6600",
    stroke: "none"
  });

  var sAnimation = Raphael.animation({
    'width': 172.3,
    'height': h,
    'x': 40.5,
    'y': y,
    fill: "#ff0066"
  }, 2000, "backOut")
  fillhouse.animate(sAnimation);


  var thehouse = paper.path("M236.5,80.4L128.9,2.1c-1.6-1.1-3.7-1.1-5.3,0L16.1,80.4c-3.5,2.6-1.7,8.1,2.6,8.1l13,0c-1,2.5-1.5,5.3-1.5,8.2l0,122.7c0,12,9.2,21.7,20.6,21.7l150.9,0c11.4,0,20.6-9.7,20.6-21.7l0-122.7c0-2.9-0.5-5.7-1.5-8.2h13C238.2,88.6,240,83,236.5,80.4z M206.7,104.9l0,106.5c0,9-6.9,16.3-15.5,16.3l-129.9,0c-8.5,0-15.5-7.3-15.5-16.3l0-106.5c0-9,6.9-16.3,15.5-16.3l129.9,0C199.8,88.6,206.7,95.9,206.7,104.9z").attr({
    fill: "#ccc",
    stroke: "none"
  });


};

//Trigger onload event while clicking the element
var clickEle = document.getElementsByClassName("clickme")[0];
clickEle.addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("frivardihouse").innerHTML = "";
  dispatchEvent(new Event('load'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<div id="frivardihouse"></div>

<div class="clickme">
  CLICK ME AND REPEAT ANIMATION
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### The simplest way to do this is as follows

#### Call reFill function on the click event

```
function reFill() {
  document.getElementById('frivardihouse').innerHTML = '';
  onload();
}
```

That's it!.

Answer (score 0):

if you are still looking for answer. I would solve a little bit different from the existing ones. Basically I would

1. not override onload by declaring onload function as global. it is a little bit difficult to follow
2. separate a method to draw and a method to animate.
3. in onload I will call draw and get an object back. this object will perform animation.
4. onClick will call animation method again
5. animation method will check if the house is already filled. if it is filled then remove the filled element only. Then it will performing to add new fill element with animation. fiddle link to check https://jsfiddle.net/hye0os7f/9/

---

```
function round(value, precision) {
  const multiplier = Math.pow(10, precision || 0);
  return Math.round(value * multiplier) / multiplier;
}
function draw() {
  const paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('frivardihouse'), 250, 250);

  const ltv = 0.6;
  const h = 144 * ltv;
  const y = 86 + (1 - ltv) * 144;
  const ltvtxt = round(ltv * 100);

  const sAnimation = Raphael.animation(
    {
      width: 172.3,
      height: h,
      x: 40.5,
      y,
      fill: '#ff0066',
    },
    2000,
    'backOut',
  );
  paper
    .path(
  'M236.5,80.4L128.9,2.1c-1.6-1.1-3.7-1.1-5.3,0L16.1,80.4c-3.5,2.6-1.7,8.1,2.6,8.1l13,0c-1,2.5-1.5,5.3-1.5,8.2l0,122.7c0,12,9.2,21.7,20.6,21.7l150.9,0c11.4,0,20.6-9.7,20.6-21.7l0-122.7c0-2.9-0.5-5.7-1.5-8.2h13C238.2,88.6,240,83,236.5,80.4z M206.7,104.9l0,106.5c0,9-6.9,16.3-15.5,16.3l-129.9,0c-8.5,0-15.5-7.3-15.5-16.3l0-106.5c0-9,6.9-16.3,15.5-16.3l129.9,0C199.8,88.6,206.7,95.9,206.7,104.9z',
    )
    .attr({ fill: '#ccc', stroke: 'none' });
  let fillhouse = null;
  return {
    paper,
    animateInHouse: () => {
      if (fillhouse) {
        fillhouse.remove();
      }
      fillhouse = paper.rect(40.5, 230, 172.3, 0).attr({ fill: '#ff6600', stroke: 'none' });
      fillhouse.animate(sAnimation);
    },
  };
}
let thePaper = null;
const pageOnLoad = function () {
  thePaper = draw();
  thePaper.animateInHouse();
};

function onRedraw() {
  thePaper.animateInHouse();
}

window.onload = pageOnLoad;
```